# how to add space at top of page

Tags: html, css

I am learning to make a simple page using html and css and the page looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpOZj.jpg
however the bigbox is too close to the top.

how to add some margin or spaces on top of it, other than using line breaks `<br>`

here is my CSS

```
root { 
display: block;
}
body {
background-color: #586B5E;
}
.bigbox {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:780px;
height:560px;
background-color:#AFBCAC;
border: 1px solid #AFBCAC;
padding: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #CCD9C8;
-webkit-box-reflect: below 15px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(85%, transparent), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.2)));
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Surat v0.1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div class="bigbox">
   </div>
     <?php
     // put your code here
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply `margin` to either the `body` or the `bigbox` element.

```
body {
    background-color: #586B5E;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

or

```
.bigbox {
    margin-top: 10px;
    ...
}
```

[CSS Margin Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
.bigbox {
margin:50px auto;
width:780px;
height:560px;
...
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works. i am a bit confused between margin and padding. now i get the idea

Comment: Remember to up-vote answers you find helpful, and select a correct answer. Beau Grantham's is very informative.

Comment: yes, sorry for late vote. stackoverflow didn't allow me to vote immediately

Answer (score 0):

You can add some margin or padding to the top of the `.bigbox` class. Try this `margin-top: 50px;`

Answer (score 0):

I often use padding-top: 1 px;

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you use margin-top to add space to the top.
Padding is used to add space inside. If you set padding to say 25px, if you put text into that box it would be 25 pixels away from the edges.